# loop with array in TCSH shell

Tags: shell, array, tcsh

In TCSH :

I'm giving two lists containing different files in it. Then I have to pass those list as an array element and then the loop should execute twice as there are only 2 lists.
But in this case loop is executing as much time as those files in both the lists.

```
set list_one = (one.s two.s three.s)
set list_two = (four.s five.s)

set arr=($list_one $list_two)

foreach i ($arr)
cat $i > $output.s
end
```

This is an example of my code, according to me loop should execute only twice(for `list_one` and `list_two`), but it's executing five times (for `one.s two.s three.s four.s five.s`)

Answer (score 2):

The assignment `set arr=($list_one $list_two)` flattens the lists into one.

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for here, but you could loop over the names of the lists with

```
set names=(list_one list_two)

foreach i ($names)
    echo $i
end
```

But getting from there to actually using the first two lists after you have their name in a variable seems trickier. I can't find if tcsh supports indirect variable references, other than via `eval`. Something like this seems to work, but getting the quoting right on the eval seems fickly:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
set l1 = (aa bb cc)
set l2 = (dd ee)
set names = (l1 l2)

foreach i ($names)
    eval set x = \(\$$i\)
    foreach j ($x)
        echo $i $j
    end
end
```

But it values containing whitespace get split, and I don't have an idea how to fix that.

---

Honestly, I'd switch away from Tcsh, and do the same in e.g. Zsh :

```
l1=(aa bb cc)
l2=(cc dd)
names=(l1 l2)

for i in $names; do
    for j in ${(P)i}; do
        echo $i $j
    done
done
```

That should deal with whitespace in the values, but does drop empty elements.

Comment: To handle list values with spaces in the tcsh version,  change to ``eval set x = \(\$$i\:q\)`` and ``foreach j ($x:q)``.